# jQuery UI autocomplete vs TextboxList autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am deciding between 2 different autocomplete plugins.

jQuery UI autocomplete  - [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

jQuery textboxlist - [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3adCqQmtlWvbIJ%3adevthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/+jquery+textboxlist&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg)

May i know what were your experiences, and which one you folks ended up going with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used jQuery UI autocomplete quite extensively for some larger e-commerce projects. I decided on the jQuery UI solution was for the following reasons (in order of importance to me and my needs for the project):

1. It was built by the jQuery team/community.
2. Because of #1, I knew the support would be much better.
3. Because of #1, I knew it would be kept up to speed w/ the latest browser advancements (and with the latest versions of jQuery).
4. Because of all of the above, I knew any future issues or requirements set by the client would be met.

None of those even address the technical aspects. I believe jQuery UI has enough options to meet pretty much any needs concerning autocomplete.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The one thing that Textboxlist has that was nice was the facebook like tokenizing. Did you miss that in jquery ui?

Comment: Joe, did you find any limitations of Jquery UI autocomplete plugin that one should be aware of before using it? Do you know any technical advantages of autocomplete plugin comparing to the competing plugins?